# When will implicit rule be applied for a makefile?

Tags: makefile

It says:

> In general,`make` searches for an
>   implicit rule for each target[1], and for
>   each double-colon rule[2], that has no
>   commands[3].

This can have two different understanding:

```
1 or (2 and 3)

(1 or 2) and 3
```

Which does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

The "has no commands" part always applies, i.e.,

```
(1 or 2) and 3
```